# Pagination widget is not working Typo3 10.4

Tags: pagination, typo3

There is a search input box to take a string in the frontend. Also there is SQL in the controller to fetch the result based on the search text. I get the expected result from the query.

I want to show those result in the frontend with pagination. In this case i have used following code

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{isin}" as="paginatedIsinDocuments" configuration="{itemsPerPage: 5, insertAbove: 0, insertBelow: 1, maximumNumberOfLinks: 100, addQueryStringMethod: 'GET,POST'}">

                <div class="row mb-4">
                    <f:for each="{paginatedIsinDocuments}" as="document">
                        <div class="col-12 fs-highlighted">
                            <a class="px-3 px-md-5 py-2" href="{document.file.originalResource.publicUrl}" target="_blank">
                                {document.file.originalResource.originalFile.name}
                                <i class="icon-download"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </f:for>
                </div>
</f:widget.paginate>
```

Unfortunately its not working. It shows all the rows in the page 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well in general you should migrate that to the [Pagination-API](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Pagination/Index.html).
The Fluid pagination widget is deprecated and [removed in V11](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Breaking-92529-AllFluidWidgetFunctionalityRemoved.html) anyway.

[Here](https://susi.dev/typo3-fluid-paginate/) is a nice article how to migrate.

Comment: i am using typo3 10.4. so pagination widget is still in this version